# How to keep the field separator when printing $0 with awk

Tags: awk

I try to modify one column of my file, then print the result.

```
awk -F"|" '{ if(NR!=1){$5 = $5+0.1} print $0}' myfile
```

It does what I want, but when printing, only the first line keeps its field separator.( the one, i don't modify).

So I could use `print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5"|"...` but isn't there a solution using $0 ? (For example if I don't know the numbers of column)

I believe, I could solve my problem easily with `sed`, but I try to learn `awk` for now.

Comment: I believe `sed` is not the correct tool for this (it doesn't understand columns). You are right in using `awk`.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to reply to answers. To thank the answerers, upvote their answer (assuming they're correct and helpful of course), and accept the one that best solves your problem (or none, if none is fully satisfactory). For more information, see [the help center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @gardenhead, not only does `sed` not understand columns, it also doesn't understand numbers at all.  It is purely for text.  It would be extraordinarily difficult and hacky to set up a `sed` command to "add 0.1 to a number".  :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

@Sukminder has already given the simple answer; I have a couple tidbits of style points and helpful syntax about your example code (like a code review).  This started as a comment but it was getting long.

`OFS` is the output field separator, as already mentioned.

`$0` is the default argument to `print`—no need to specify it explicitly.  And another style point: `awk` has what's called "patterns", which are like built-in conditional blocks.  So you could also just use:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} NR != 1 {$5 += 0.1} {print}' myfile
```

Comment: And the default action for a true condition is `print`, so `{print}` is often condensed to `1`.

Comment: @muru, very true.  I was going to mention it but was running out the door.  :)

Answer (score 17):

You can set the [*Output Field Separator*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_03), `OFS`.

```
'BEGIN { OFS = "|" } ...'
```

Or:

```
'BEGIN { OFS = FS } ...'
```

It is *<space>* by default.